# views exposed filter listen to node form values

Tags: ajax, views, nodes

If view block with exposed filer or contextual filter is placed on node/add , node/edit form and node is having some field which could be used alternate to exposed filter or contextual filter. Is this setup possible?
ex:

```
views block having taxonomy exposed filter with select list widget
node form having same taxonomy (vocabulary) field with select list widget.
```

when selecting the select list on node form views block should be change.Views exposed filter would be made display:none by css if this is possible.

One possible way I am thinking is php code in "provide default value"(listen to field change?) or this has to be passed by node form on field value change.

[image: pass node form value to view block with ajax]

Comment: I suppose you need to write custom js: on field input get it's value, pass it to exposed filter and submit exposed form with ajax.

Comment: @T-34 I thought of that but couldn't it possible to watch/listen form field changes from view when it is able to use ajax? Just a hope :).